# Automatically perform “Run” when Apply Changes fails

Tags: android, android-studio

Sometimes when runnig my app, **Apply Code Changes** or **Apply Code Changes and Restart Activity** run options are failing and it is very inconvinient/annoying to click on **Run app** option again.

How to make sure that when those 2 options fail, Android Studio automatically **runs app** without showing error message and without me clicking on **Run app** option in the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Android Studio 3.5 you can follow following steps to enable this. Instructions are for Windows. For Mac there might be some slight differences:

1. Go to **File**
2. Find **Settings** (or simple click `CTRL+ALT+S`)
3. Find **Build, Execution, Deployment** from left menu bar
4. Find **Deployment** sub menu inside **Build, Execution, Deployment**
5. Tick both of the options. Look at the picture below:

[image]